# Sending raw audio bytes from Javascript client to Spring Web Socket Handler

Tags: javascript, java, spring, web-audio-api, spring-websocket

What's the best way to send raw audio bytes to a web socket handler in spring? I have the following web socket handler which can receive text messages correctly from client.

```
public class TranscribeHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    WebSocketSession session;

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    this.session = session;
    System.out.println("Connection established Transcribe");
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession var1, WebSocketMessage<?> var2) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Got message");
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession var1, CloseStatus var2) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Connection closed");
}

@Override
public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
    return false;
}}
```

Here's client code that processes audio from microphone

```
this.ws = new $WebSocket("ws://localhost:8082/transcribe");
//Creates a websocket session with server successfully

var scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(256, 1, 1);
var scriptNode.addEventListener('audioprocess', function(e) {
  var audioBytes = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  this.ws.send(audioBytes).publish().connect();
}
```

The audioBytes I get is a 'Float32Array', which I am sending directly to the server socket session. The server handler receives this message in string format which looks something like this:

{"0":-0.0005212430842220783,"1":-0.0008100871928036213,"2":-0.0008365644607692957,"3":-0.0020894776098430157,"4":-0.0006563755450770259, 
...
...
254":-0.0005547034088522196,"255":0.0010016305604949594}

I want to convert this string message into raw bytes[]. How do I do that? I am thinking there should be a simple way of directly sending the audio bytes through a socket instead of me processing the string format. If anyone has tried to do this please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any solutions?